# Add arrow to plot with different axes scales without skewing arrow's head

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I add an arrow to a Matplotlib plot with different axes scales without skewing the arrow's head? I currently see the behavior below when calling the following function on a plot where the x-axis and y-axis have different ranges:

[A Matplotlib plot with arrows. The axes scales are different which seems to skew the arrow heads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCYt8.png)

The function I call to create arrows:

```
def drawArrow(A, B, axis):
    axis.arrow(A[0], A[1], B[0] - A[0], B[1] - A[1], head_width=0.2, head_length=10)
```